# Putting a fade in fadeout Effect on objective C

Tags: objective-c, animation, background

I want this to be a background in my app for Ipad.
I'm building everything in objective C (native app)

I need a little help figuring out how to animate each of the triangles over the image (overlay) so it fades in and out independently of each other, the goal to make a constant shimmer like effect so the image doesn't feel sos tatic. Do i have to animate each triangle independently? Is there any algorithm that i should be looking at so it seems kinda random but isn't.

Here is the background image

[image]

I need some guidance on where to start and how to approach this problem, and feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Any time I see something advertised as "Not a virus", I get a bit leery. For that reason, I have inlined the image in your post, using imgur, SO's trusted image provider.

Comment: thanks for that! i dont have a high enough reputation to inline the image

Comment: You should soon! Welcome to the site, and I hope you get an answer that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, thanks alot. coding is a giant learning curve its crazy. I've been staring at code for weeks and i still dont understand it :D

Comment: Have you implemented the triangle part yet (splitting the background image in triangles)?

Comment: yes i have already separated the triangles and the background. I merged them into the background for explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a)**  My advice is to use UIViewAnimationWithBlocks introduced in iOS 4. If you have a solid grasp on blocks, they can be very useful. Here's an example I created in as little as 5 minutes to illustrate:

```
typedef void(^FadeInOutBlock)(void);

@interface PMViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) FadeInOutBlock fadeInOutBlock;
@end
```

Here we declare a typedef to save us from doing the block syntax all over again. We also create a property to hold the animation block.

```
@implementation PMViewController
@synthesize myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    __block PMViewController *_self = self;


    self.fadeInOutBlock = ^{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            // fade out effect
            _self.myView.alpha = 0.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL success){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                // fade in effect
                _self.myView.alpha = 1.0f;
            } completion:^(BOOL success){
                // recursively fire a new animation
                if (_self.fadeInOutBlock)
                    _self.fadeInOutBlock();
            }];
        }];
    };
}
```

We create the animation, within an animation. You start off with the fade out, where myView's alpha will be reduced to 0.0f in 0.5f seconds. After it's completed, a second animation will be fired, restoring the alpha for myView back to 1.0f and finally, firing out the first animation, again. (Animception)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.fadeInOutBlock)
        self.fadeInOutBlock();
}

@end
```

And finally, in view did appear you fire it off for the first time.

**b)**

Now, for the shimmering animation that you mention, I suggest you separate each triangle into it's own UIView and use the technique above, using different durations and alphas.

If you have to many small UIViews, group them up into a bigger UIView (by using the addSubview method) and apply the animation to those 'container' UIViews.

For instance, you could have four separate UIView containers, that have a bunch of separate UIViews as their children. You could then create four block animations, one for each container, and then apply the animation to them. I bet experimenting with that, you would be able to create pretty good effects.

Comment: By the way, this example is using ARC, so the whole memory management for blocks is being handled automatically. Keep this in mind.

Comment: Hey pmd,  this seems to make sense. I'll try it out and get back to you. THanks!!

Comment: It works so far. But it shifts the entire layer fade in and out. I'm trying to make each triangle flow in and out seamlessly, making it seem like they're independant, but has a flutter effect- any ideas?

Comment: You will have to treat each triangle as a separate view. No other way I can think of.

Comment: update, i've created a UIgridview and included each triangle into it. seems to work, but needs more work. git link going to be posted soon. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any special librarys. So you need to create a black `UIView` with an alpha of 0. Then create an `NSTimer` that increases the alpha of the `UIView`.

Comment: yeah, i figured that was one way of doing it, the problem with that was that you will be moving the entire layer from alpha 0 to 100, this doesn't really give the independent animation i am looking for.  What is the best approach to giving each triangle a life of its own?

Maybe each triangle into an array and randomly change a Boolean to fade in and out??



I know many other applications want to use something like this, so i will be posting this on git once its done.